# TCP/IP server client

Tags: 12.04, server

I just started using Linux. I have dual boot setup and I am familiar with socket programming but on windows in visual studio c#. Now I am trying to build a simple application that will run on Ubuntu.

I have some questions like were to start?

If one for instance server is running on windows can client be on Ubuntu? Can I just write the code in eclipse compile and run it or I need first to preform some configuration in terminal window for Linux?

I want to understand and learn how to  send data wireless form one PC to another without using ROUTER in a middle if it's possible? And with router in a middle then it suppose to be simpler I think.

Comment: What does a router have to do with TCP sockets here? If hosts can reach each other then TCP can perfectly set up a connection to the remote host. Please include in your question what you have tried/found exactly (include code and links). Also: what programming language are we talking about here for Ubuntu? Or do you even only need a shell script? Please **edit** your question to include all this information and try to improve your post as well (you're not likely to get any answers here as it currently stands).

Comment: By the way, a quick search for doing this in Python (works for virtually all operating systems): http://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication

Comment: Have you tried to Google on the subject? because there's a lot out there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If one for instance server is running on windows can client be on Ubuntu?

The TCP/IP suite is the TCP/IP suite. It does not matter if that runs on Ubuntu, Windows or any other OS. The data on the network is in a well described format, regardless of the OS or even the CPU's [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

> Can I just write the code in eclipse compile and run it or I need first to perform some configuration in terminal window for Linux?

To use TCP over IP (or UDP over IP, or ICMP) you will need to configure the network the regular way. There is nothing special of different between you have learned how to do that in windows or in a Linux distribution.

> I want to understand and learn how to send data wireless form one PC to another without using ROUTER in a middle if it's possible?

That is called an ad-hoc wireless network. Your wireless cards needs to support that.

> And with router in a middle then it suppose to be simpler I think

I assume that with router you mean a wireless access point?
Because a normal router does not do wireless.

(Disclaimer: many devices are a combination of (Fibre|ADSL-)modem, router and wireless access point. However these are still separate function and you really should understand how things work.)

I suggest that you start with learning the basic way how TCP/IP works and then look up how wireless works. If you still have problems after that come back and ask a specific single question.

[This is a nice place to start](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work).